# Incremental online backup using Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, backup, delphi-7

I am trying to implement a new feature in our Delpi project that will help our users to make backups online on our servers, so I've used Indy FTP component to build a form that will upload / download the user files or folders

But I need to offer the ability to do incremental backups. Where our users can only upload ONLY 'new' differences to their files and folders. So for example if I have a text file with size 5 KB, and I've added text to it worth additional 2 KB, then the backup will just upload those extra 2 KB and NOT the whole 7 KB

So can someone please recommend any approach, algorithm to start with?

Thanks for your time

Note: we are using Delphi 7

Comment: Find a library that does diffing and patching. Then use it.

Comment: What are you going to backup? Regular files? Databases? Mostly binary? Text?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Tried to search the web for Diffing and patching libs but couldn't find any, so any suggestions / recommendations on any lib?

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen I've tried searching the web for any implementation of rsync in Delphi but couldn't find any components or code samples. Do you happen to know if there is any components / code samples for rsync under Delphi?

Comment: Well, GNU diff and patch spring to mind.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera Anything, text files, binaries, database files...in other words any files or folders...no specific type

Comment: You don't implement RSYNC in delphi, you just invoke it. It's a command line utility program, originally found on Unix but available as a windows port (still, just a command line utility). You can write your own GUI wrapper for it in delphi.

Comment: As Warren says. Just wrap rsync. Invoke rsync.exe with the right parameters and it should work. Remember to check exit code. You can read stdout/stderr of rsync when you want to implement a progressbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Microsoft Delta Compression API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417345.aspx) that will allow you to diff and patch, however I have investigated this route before and found that using rSync or robocopy is a much easier route - especially as it will be quite hard to apply the patch/changes from the server side unless you build your own custom FTP server.

Comment: Any thoughts where I can find code samples / components for rSync / robocopy under Delphi

Comment: You would just be launching an executable and capturing its output in delphi. The rsync executable is a command line utility, and you install it by grabbing the installer from somewhere like here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sereds/files/cwRsync/